# How Download .text files using java script

Tags: javascript

I download the file using script function, using iframe load and new page load.

Using this method i download the all format file , but i can't able to download .txt file

Please help me to download file

```
if(split[length-1]!="JPEG" && split[length-1]!="bmp" && split[length-1]!="pdf" && split[length-1]!="JPG" && split[length-1]!="jpg" && split[length-1]!="jpeg" && split[length-1]!="png" && split[length-1]!="gif") {
    $("body").append("<iframe src='" + file_path + "' style='display: none;' ></iframe>");
}
else {
    window.open(file_path);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with downloading text files? Any errors?

Comment: Nothing you can do without a server and server side code - browsers will open text files as plain text and won't bring the open/save dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Like Shadow Wizard said, this would work, if you were pointing the iframe to a url that sends back [certain headers](http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm). This is only possible with server side scripts, such as PHP:

```
<?php
// download.php
if (!$_GET['url']) die();
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
$url = 'http://' . str_replace('http://', '', $url); // Stop accessing local file system.
$filename = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
$mime = mime_content_type($filename);

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
header('Content-type: '. $mime);
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

Then you only need to edit your javascript to pass the url through this `download.php` file.

```
if(split[length-1]!="JPEG" && split[length-1]!="bmp" && split[length-1]!="pdf" && split[length-1]!="JPG" && split[length-1]!="jpg" && split[length-1]!="jpeg" && split[length-1]!="png" && split[length-1]!="gif") {
    $("body").append("<iframe src='download.php?url=" + file_path + "' style='display: none;' ></iframe>");
}
else {
    window.open(file_path);
}
```